# malloc in kernel

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel

When I try to use `malloc` in a kernel module I get an error message from the compiler. My code:

```
res=(ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
```

The compilers error message is:

```
/root/ex3/ex3mod.c:491: error: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’
```

What should I do?

Comment: in other words as we all know #include <stdlib.h> doesnt exist in kernel 
what include should i had ?

Answer (score 24):

Note about the difference between the two allocation methods - `kmalloc` and `kmem_cache`, or `vmalloc`:

`kmalloc`: Best used for fast allocations that are smaller than a page (PAGE_SIZE, 0x1000 on most architectures). It doesn't involve mapping memory, so you get the memory straight from the kernel's 1:1 physical memory mapping. You get physically contingent memory. Note that if you want to allocate *more than* one page (i.e. order > 0), you risk bumping into external fragmentation issues - i.e. the call might fail even if there is enough free. Higher order - higher chance for allocation failure, and up-time plays a factor here too.

If you want to achieve maximal allocation efficiency then using your own `kmem_cache` for each type of struct is the way to go (the other benefits for this strategy are being able to monitor the state of your allocations from `/proc` and catching memory leaks more easily).

`vmalloc`: Allocations of more than one page. You get mapped-memory in kernel space. Behind the scenes it is similar to what userspace gets - the kernel allocates a bunch of pages and maps them in a virtual address space. This allocation is slower than `kmalloc`'s, and memory accesses might incur a bit more overhead.

Answer (score 21):

Use [`kmalloc`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-kmalloc.html) or [`vmalloc`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-vmalloc.html) instead (see also [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20131208033328/http://www.fiveanddime.net:80/man-pages/kmalloc.9.html))

Comment: Or `vmalloc()`.  Memory allocation works differently in the kernel.

Comment: these links are dead; perfect example of why link-only answers are a bad idea. this answer is at the top of a google search for "can i use malloc in a kernel module?".

Answer (score 7):

You can't use libraries in the kernel. None whatsoever.

This means that ANY function you're calling in the kernel needs to be defined in the kernel. Linux does not define a malloc, hence you can't use it.

There is a memory allocator and a family of memory allocation functions. Read the kernel docs on the memory allocator for more information.

Incidentially, there are  a few functions the kernel defines which are in the standard C library as well; this is for convenience.

It does, for instance, defined [snprintf](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.34/lib/vsprintf.c#L1459)

Answer (score 2):

use kmalloc/kfree. You may grep malloc in kernel source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can imagine it like a three step process:

1. User space library -    malloc()
2. System call -    brk()
3. Inside Kernel - kmalloc/vmalloc/gfp etc routines of memory manager

So If you are already at step 3, writing kernel module, then going back wouldn't make sense. So you need to use the kernel routines only for memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you should use kmalloc and friends, check the linux kernel for examples. e.g.:
http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.0/drivers/infiniband/hw/mthca/mthca_provider.c#L1033